# Should I implement IEnumerable (and how)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a class in my accounts model:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want to use the `Enumerable.Single()` method in a command in the control class, like this:

`UserProfile userProfile = UserProfile.Single(x => x.UserId==id);`

Where `id` is parameter from user input. Therefore I implement `IEnumerable<UserProfile>` to `UserProfile`. VS gives me 2 errors in the model class:

```
AppName.Models.UserProfile' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'
AppName.Models.UserProfile' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.UserProfile>.GetEnumerator()'
```

And in the controller class

```
AppName.Models.UserProfile does not contain a definition for 'Single'
```

The question is should I implement `IEnumerable` on the `UserProfile` class? I thought `Single()` only deals with `IEnumerable`. If so, in my case, how should I implement that?

---

**SOLUTION**: I was confused. The solution is:

```
UsersContext context = new UsersContext();
            UserProfile userProfile = context.UserProfiles.Single(u => u.UserId==id);
```

Wher `UserProfiles` is a `DBSet` defined in the `UsersContext` class.

Comment: Sounds like you're misunderstanding what .Single is for. What is it you're actually trying to do? Your class describes a single instance of a UserProfile so somewhere else should be exposing an IEnumerable<UserProfile> for you to do queries against.

Comment: @PhonicUK seems like I misunderstood. I want to use the Entity framework's `single()` but I read some wrong documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using Entity Framework. To access your `UserProfile` from database you first need to create a context of your `DbContext`
For example:

```
using(var context = new MyContext())
{
  UserProfile profile = context.UserProfile.Single(u => u.UserId == id);
}
```

Now I think you are just using the method on the class `UserProfile` or something, that's not a collection of userprofiles (not even a single userprofile as it's not instantiated for that matter).